# ModuleNotFoundError popping after mentioning 'tags' in the installed apps list

Tags: python, django

How do I resolve the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tags'` error　in my python django code?

After adding　‘tags’ in the installed apps of settings.py, i am getting the no module named tags error.
How may I resolve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is `tags`? Is it one of your modules or a package you installed?
If it's an external lib, are you sure you installed it?